# Why is append() not following the condition of the if statement?

Tags: python, list

This section of code is supposed to check if the neighboring points exist as part of the `points` list.

- The `points` list is a given.
- The `check` list is currently only checking the first item of the `points` list.
- The `counted` list is supposed to show the points that exist within the `points` list that neighbor the first given point.
- The `rowNbr` and `colNbr` are the following conditions of what points neighbor a given point.

```
points = [[3,2],[4,2],[4,3],[5,2],[5,3],[6,4]]
temp = [[3,2],[4,2],[4,3],[5,2],[5,3],[6,4]]
check = []
counted = []


rowNbr = [1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1]
colNbr = [0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1]

check.append(points[0])

for j in range(len(check)):
    for i in range(len(rowNbr)):
        temp[j][0] = check[j][0] + rowNbr[i]
        temp[j][1] = check[j][1] + colNbr[i]


        if temp[j] in points:
            counted.append(temp[:])


print(counted)
```

I want it to print: `[[4, 2], [4, 3]]`

It prints out the following:

```
[[[2, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [5, 2], [5, 3], [6, 4]], [[2, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [5, 2], [5, 3], [6, 4]]]
```

If I include a `print(temp[j])` line within the `if temp[j] in points:` loop, it prints the corect coordinates, but the `counted` list is wrong and printing out everything.

Why is this error occurring and how do I fix it?

Comment: and what happens if you do `counted.append(temp[j])`?

Comment: I did only ```temp[j]``` initially, and it printed out ```[[2, 1], [2, 1]]``` which I'm not sure how it got.

Comment: `counted.append(temp[:])` is appending an entire copy of the temp array as an element of `counted`.  Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`counted.append(temp[:])` appends a copy of the whole temp array each time it is executed -- if you just want it to append a copy of temp[j], do `counted.append(temp[j][:])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an element in the reference to `temp[:]` (should be `counted.append(temp[j][:])` instead of `counted.append(temp[:])`:

```
points = [[3,2],[4,2],[4,3],[5,2],[5,3],[6,4]]
temp = [[3,2],[4,2],[4,3],[5,2],[5,3],[6,4]]
check = []
counted = []


rowNbr = [1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1]
colNbr = [0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1]

check.append(points[0])

for j in range(len(check)):
    for i in range(len(rowNbr)):
        temp[j][0] = check[j][0] + rowNbr[i]
        temp[j][1] = check[j][1] + colNbr[i]


        if temp[j] in points:
            counted.append(temp[j][:])


print(counted)
```